# Button unclickable upon rendering of Window

Tags: .net, wpf, button, rendering

I have a WPF application that will not allow me to click a button until a little bit of time has past, but this behavior is random where it only happens some of the time. Most of the time the Window renders and I am able to click said button right away.

Main Window:

```
    <views:StatusBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" Visibility="{Binding Editing, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleConverter}}" />
</DockPanel>
```

User Control:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <!--Read Button-->
    <Button Content="Read "   x:Name="ReadBtn"     Command="{Binding ReadCMD}"    Padding="10,5" Margin= "10,0" IsEnabled="{Binding ReadEnabled}" />

    <!--Save Button-->
    <Button Content="Save "   x:Name="SaveBtn"     Command="{Binding SaveCMD}"    Padding="10,5" Margin= "10,0" IsEnabled="{Binding SaveEnabled}" 
            Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSaveNeeded}" Value="Yes">
                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FlashBackground">
                                <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" RepeatBehavior="Forever" >
                                    <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color" Duration="00:00:00.25" AutoReverse="True" To="Red" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FlashBackground" />
                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>

    <!--Load Button-->
    <Button Content="Load "   x:Name="LoadBtn"     Command="{Binding LoadCMD}"    Padding="10,5" Margin= "10,0" IsEnabled="{Binding LoadEnabled}" />

    <!--Print Button-->
    <Button Content="Print"   x:Name="PrintBtn"    Command="{Binding PrintCMD}"   Padding="10,5" Margin= "10,0" IsEnabled="{Binding PrintEnabled}" />

    <!--Exit Button-->
    <Button Content="Exit"    x:Name="ExitBtn"     Command="{Binding ExitCMD}"    Padding="10,5" Margin= "10,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

View Model

```
private bool _tab1_Selected;
    public bool tab1_Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return _tab1_Selected;
        }
        set
        {
            _tab1_Selected = value;

            if (value)
            {
                CommMode = (byte)PacketType.tab1_DUMP;

                if (tab1needsSaving)
                {
                    IsSaveNeeded = SaveNeeded.Yes;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsSaveNeeded = SaveNeeded.No;
                }
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("tab1_Selected");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SaveEnabled");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProgramEnabled");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Editing");
        }
    }


    private bool _tab2_Selected;
    public bool tab2_Selected
    {
        get
        {
            return _tab2_Selected;
        }
        set
        {
            _tab2_Selected = value;

            if (value)
            {
                CommMode = (byte)PacketType.tab2_DUMP;

                if (tab2needsSaving)
                {
                    IsSaveNeeded = SaveNeeded.Yes;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsSaveNeeded = SaveNeeded.No;
                }
            }

            NotifyPropertyChanged("tab2_Selected");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SaveEnabled");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProgramEnabled");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Editing");
        }
    }


public bool Editing
    {
        get
        {
            return tab2_Selected || tab1_Selected;
        }
    }

 private bool _saveEnabled;
    public bool SaveEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            //return _saveEnabled;
            return ((tab1_Selected && tab1Data != null && tab1Data.Count > 0) || (tab2_Selected && tab2Data != null && tab2Data.Count > 0) && _saveEnabled);
        }
        set
        {
            _saveEnabled = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SaveEnabled");
        }
    }

 private bool _programEnabled;
    public bool ProgramEnabled
    {
        get
        {
            //return _saveEnabled;
            return ((tab1_Selected && tab1Data != null && tab1Data.Count > 0) || (tab2_Selected && tab2Data != null && tab2Data.Count > 0) && _programEnabled);
        }
        set
        {
            _programEnabled = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProgramEnabled");
        }
    }
```

Commands:

```
    public ICommand ReadCMD     { get; set; }
    public ICommand SaveCMD     { get; set; }
    public ICommand LoadCMD     { get; set; }
    public ICommand ProgramCMD  { get; set; }
    public ICommand PrintCMD    { get; set; }
    public ICommand ExitCMD     { get; set; }

    // In MainVM constructor
    ReadCMD = new RelayCommand(ReadSettings);
    SaveCMD = new RelayCommand(SaveSettings);
    LoadCMD = new RelayCommand(LoadSettings);
    ProgramCMD = new RelayCommand(ProgramSettings);
    PrintCMD = new RelayCommand(PrintSettings);
    ExitCMD = new RelayCommand(ExitProgram);
```

Relay Command Class:

```
 public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> execute;

    private Predicate<object> canExecute;

    private event EventHandler CanExecuteChangedInternal;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, DefaultCanExecute)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }

        if (canExecute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("canExecute");
        }

        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            this.CanExecuteChangedInternal += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            this.CanExecuteChangedInternal -= value;
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute != null && this.canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }

    public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        EventHandler handler = this.CanExecuteChangedInternal;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            //DispatcherHelper.BeginInvokeOnUIThread(() => handler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty));
            handler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void Destroy()
    {
        this.canExecute = _ => false;
        this.execute = _ => { return; };
    }

    private static bool DefaultCanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I switched from a `DockPanel` to a `StackPanel` and set a width to the `StatusBox` instead of allowing the `LastChildFill` to adjust the status field and this fixed my problem. Even though I put a border around the `StatusBox` to see where it was rendering, it was still giving me issues.

Comment: Please explain the properties for `SaveEnabled` etc or post more code. It is hard to find an error in a binding if half of it is missing.

Comment: @Ihildebrandt - I have added the SaveEnabled and ProgramEnabled properties for you.

Comment: Is it the button with `SaveEnabled`, that is causing trouble? And BTW how does your `ICommand` implementation looks like?

Comment: I added the ICommand information. It is the Read button that is giving me the issue. The Save button is disabled when the program first starts.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to explicitely bind to a SaveEnabled property for the button to be dis-/enabled depending on whether or not the command can be executed.
Just include your CanExecute logic in the predicate of your RelayCommand and if the property changes, call OnCanExecuteChanged on your command to enable the button.

**Edit**

Something like this

```
private ICommand saveCMD;

public ICommand SaveCMD     
{ 
   get
   {
      if(this.saveCMD == null)
      {
         this.saveCMD = new RelayCommand(this.SaveSettings, this.CanSaveSettings)
      }

      return saveCMD;
   }
}

public bool CanSaveSettings()
{
     return ((tab1_Selected && tab1Data != null && tab1Data.Count > 0) || (tab2_Selected && tab2Data != null && tab2Data.Count > 0) && _saveEnabled);
}
```

And then in your view you should be able to just use this and it should work:

```
<Button Content="Save" x:Name="SaveBtn" Command="{Binding SaveCMD}" Padding="10,5" Margin= "10,0"/>
```

Comment: @Ihildebrandt, can you give an example. I have done this before on other projects and couldn't get the UI to refresh the button(s), and had to switch to a property that invoked the Property Changed event. Hence, why I have written it the way it is.

Comment: Edited my main post. Please check if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't help. Every so often after the program launches I still can not click the Read button right away.

Comment: Maybe the logic for the read command takes too long? Try to set a breakpoint and find out, when the predicate for the command is first time called vs. first time true.